# Move files from one doc lib to another doc lib

Tags: document-library

How do I move files from Doc Lib A to Doc Lib B that is on another site collection?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to keep metadata then the open with windows explorer is a good option.

Comment: Actually with Windows Explore if you Cut and Paste, then SP will move the item to target Doc Lib with it's Meta-Data.

Answer (score 0):

Export the document library using the [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) command. Use [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) for restoration (see options in the commands for targeting site-level and also the Site & Document Lib templates should match in the source & destination).